# Ubuntu 14.04 - tc not working

Tags: ubuntu, traffic-shaping

I have used tc before on another servers to restrict the total bandwidth available on port 80, in order to make sure that there is enough throughput for port 22 during peak hours of the day. I need some help with the reason why the following tc rules fail now:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 2 htb default 1
tc class add dev eth0 parent 2: classid 2:6 htb rate 1048576kbit
tc class add dev eth0 parent 2:6 classid 2:100d htb rate 911360Kbit
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 2: protocol ip pref 4 u32 match ip sport 80 0xffff classid 2:100d
```

Upon adding the last line (the filter add one) I get the following error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
We have an error talking to the kernel
```

Kernel version is 3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64, OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You booted your OVH server with the OVH-provided custom kernel, instead of the kernel provided by your Linux distribution. The kernel provided by OVH may not have all of the modules that you need. Reconfigure your dedicated server to [boot from the hard disk](http://help.ovh.com/KernelInstall), in your OVH account management pages.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. I booted with the correct kernel and it works. Thanks you for your time, I appreciate it.